# I need "multiple scopes" inside a event listener method in a class ("this" scope) JavaScript drag and drop API

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, this, event-listener

(Im new to JS)

Im coding a web app that consist in a 4x4 table with numeric pieces from 1 to 15 and an empty space.

I was messing with the **drag&drop API**, then I noticed that **my methods for the event listeners have a different scope than other methods.**

*sample code*

```
class game() {
  // constructors and a bunch of methods
  
  this.4x4table = [...] // One variable that I need to access

  // My problematic method here
  handleDrop(ev) {
    // Basically grabbing info from handleDrag dataTransfer and changing the target
    // element with the source element

    // There is no problem with above, but the problem starts when I try to update my
    // 4x4 grid representation of the game (a 2D array in the class game)

    this.4x4table[0][0] // Cant reach
  }
}
```

I tried using arrow functions but then I didnt knew how to access the target element variables that I was accessing with "this" before.

Comment: `this.4x4table` this is wrong. Property names cannot start with a digit in js.

Comment: I know, its a sample, not like this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind about that scope issue or whatever it is. "Object oriented" doesn't mean that everything should be in a class. I think that you should separate the game class from the "presentation" of the game. Ultimately you should be able to play the game without the UI.

So, here I have a class that has nothing to do with the UI. You can play the game just by instantiating an object and call `move()`, `positions()` and `checkState()`.

On the dropHandler the game should off course be updated (calling `move()`) and you can also check the state of the game.

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.result = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.table = [2, 3, 1, 4];
  }
  move(dragged_id, target_id) {
    let dragged_index = this.table.indexOf(dragged_id);
    let target_index = this.table.indexOf(target_id);
    this.table[dragged_index] = target_id;
    this.table[target_index] = dragged_id;
  }
  positions() {
    return this.table.join(',');
  }
  checkState() {
    return this.table.reduce((state, value, i) => {
      return (state) ? value == this.result[i] : state;
    });
  }
}

const game = new Game();

const board = document.getElementById('board');
board.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler);
board.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler);
board.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler);

function dragStartHandler(e) {
  let dragged = e.target.closest('li');
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', dragged.dataset.num);
}

function dragOverHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let num = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  let dragged = board.querySelector(`li[data-num="${num}"]`);
  let target = e.target.closest('li');
  if (target && target.dataset.num != num) {
    let dragged_clone = dragged.cloneNode(true);
    board.insertBefore(dragged_clone, target);
    board.insertBefore(target, dragged);
    dragged.remove();
    game.move(parseInt(num), parseInt(target.dataset.num));
  }
  if(game.checkState()){
    console.log('You win!');
  }
}
```

```css
ul#board {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  gap: 3px;
}

ul#board li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid black thin;
}
```

```html
<ul id="board">
  <li draggable="true" data-num="2">2</li>
  <li draggable="true" data-num="3">3</li>
  <li draggable="true" data-num="1">1</li>
  <li draggable="true" data-num="4">4</li>
</ul>
```